# How to read email as they go out or come in in exchange

Tags: .net, service, exchange-server

I am trying to create a service where i can read email (based on subject) as they go out or comes in and save the email back to Database.

I can read from a mail box but i need something like everytime a email comes in check the subject and then do something.

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Exchange server is on-premise, a transport agent might work for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877026(v=exchg.150).aspx